# Kafka-ui, 500 internal server error (timeout)

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a working server with kafka, I use vpn to connect to it. I installed via docker-compose kafka-ui. I am getting 500 errors when querying brokers and topics. I can't change the kafka options on the server. For my colleagues, exactly the same docker-compose.yml work fine (someone has Linux, someone has Mac OS). My system is ubuntu 16.

```
version: '2' 

services:    
   kafka-ui:     
      container_name: kafka-ui     
      image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest     
      ports:       
         - 8081:8080     
      environment:       
         KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME: stage       
         KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: <host>:9092       
         KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_PROPERTIES_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SASL_PLAINTEXT      
         KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_PROPERTIES_SASL_MECHANISM: PLAIN       
         KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_PROPERTIES_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="user" password="pass";'
         KAFKA_CLUSTERS_1_NAME: prod       
         KAFKA_CLUSTERS_1_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: <host>:9092       
         KAFKA_CLUSTERS_1_PROPERTIES_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: SASL_PLAINTEXT      
         KAFKA_CLUSTERS_1_PROPERTIES_SASL_MECHANISM: PLAIN       
         KAFKA_CLUSTERS_1_PROPERTIES_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="user" password="pass";'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA3GE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLtB6.png)

Requests on the site to receive brokers and topics end with a 500 error.

Using the nc command, I checked the availability of the broker from docker.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOQdf.png)

Comment: Please add logs as text, not images. Plus, your first two images look the exact same?